# How do I access my D-link Share Center NAS?

Tags: 12.10, samba, nas

Newish to ubuntu, installed 12.10 yesterday and am trying to access my dlink share center (NAS) on my home network.

When I go to browse network, it shows up but will not access my files because it's "unable to mount location" failed to retrieve share list from server - is the message.

Can some one point me to a tutorial on how to set this up? I figure I need to do something with samba but am a little rusty with that , and would like it to auto mount at bootup of computer Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For adding a permant mount you have to edit the file `/etc/fstab`. Open a terminal and type

```
sudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

In that file you have to add a line like this:

```
//mynas/share /mnt/mynas smbfs username=user,password=password 0 0
```

In this line `mynas` is the name or IP adress of you NAS. `share` is the name of the Samba share on that NAS. That one you will have to know. `/mnt/mynas` is the folder you want to have it mounted to on your local machine. You have to create that one.

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/mynas
```

And `user` and `password` are the login data for your NAS if you have any.

After editing the file run

```
sudo mount /mnt/mynas
```

to mount the new entry without having to reboot. Of course it will be mounted on reboot from now on.

Comment: Thanks for the quick direction, just one more newb question, does it matter where I add the line in gedit, and has anyone had this issue in 12.04 lts cuz 12.10 is not as stable as i'd like so far thanks again!

Comment: It doesn't matter where to add the line. I'm not using Samba myself right now, so no idea about the issue in different version. But I find 12.10 a lot unstable and buggy too...

Comment: thanx again, didn't work yet but i guess I need to install samba still, thought it came with. gonna try again tomorrow but think I'll go with 12.04 cuz 12.10 just crashed again boooo!